Error mounting USB drive: "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error"
I am unable to access my USB drive (/dev/sdc1). When I try to mount it at /media/pc, I get the following error:
USB Drive: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc1,
           missing codepage or helper program, or other error


The error from mount is generic and not the real error.  Check the kernel errors in /var/log/syslog for the real error.

Was the disk in question last used on a Windows system with the "Fast boot" setting enabled?
The Windows "Fast Boot" (Windows defaults to "ON") setting leaves the disk partition in an undocumented, proprietary state that Linux isn't permitted to recognize. Boot back into Windows and disable "Fast Boot". Be prepared to have to re-disable "Fast Boot"  - Windows updates have been known to turn it back on. See https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup

This error showed up for me when an unresponsive Ubuntu had to be cold rebooted while the external disk was still connected and worked from.

I found two solutions that worked for me.
Solution 1:

Open the Disks app.
Select the USB device.
Click on Additional partition options.
Select Edit Mount Options and turn off User Session Defaults.

Solution 2 (if Solution 1 doesn't work):

Run the Disks app.
Select the USB device.
Click on Repair Filesystem.

